# SQL specific item on top row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently developing a query for our inventory record.

Records will be used as a datasource for my dropdown object. However, I would like to add a row name "ALL" that can be used to search all products and put it on the top of the row.

```
SELECT 111 AS barcode, 'ALL' AS description
UNION ALL
SELECT barcode, description 
FROM inventory i 
ORDER BY Description ASC
```

Result:

```
AAA battery
ALL
Bunny
Charcoal
```

Desired result:

```
ALL
AAA battery
Bunny
Charcoal
```

Please help - how can I achieve the desired output?

I am using SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce a computed column into your union query and order by it:

```
SELECT barcode, description
FROM
(
    SELECT 'ALL', 'ALL', 1 AS pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT barcode, description, 2 FROM inventory
) t
ORDER BY pos, description;
```